# Short horror/sci fi story about child locked in a basement coming out after a nuclear explosion

Tags: short-stories

This is a short horror story I read several years ago.  I stumbled upon it accidentally while browsing the internet, and read it online as it was described as a horror sci fi masterpiece. My memory may have twisted some details, but this is how I remember it.

The story is from the point of view of a child locked in a basement for a long time. They make drawings on the walls of the sun.

The child is told about monsters in the outside world. There are hints of nuclear war approaching, but this is outside of the child's perspective and understanding.

A nuclear bomb explodes, and the child, protected in the basement,  believes the flash of light is related to the sun drawn on the wall.

The child escapes, and there are badly burnt survivors stumbling through the street. The child picks up a weapon and starts attacking them, as the child believes these are the monsters they were told of.